remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied. The provided password or token is incorrect or your account has 2FA enabled
My gitlab CI pipleline is failing by throwing the following error:
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied. The provided password or token is incorrect or your account has 2FA enabled and you must use a personal access token instead of a password. See http://gitlab.example.com/help/topics/git/troubleshooting_git#error-on-git-fetch-http-basic-access-denied
fatal: Authentication failed for 'http://gitlab.example.com/example/repo.git/'

I have private repos on which I am facing these issues. However, this issue is not consistent, means 70% of the time the CI pipeline passes without this issue and rest of the time it failed by throwing the above error.
The project whose CI pipeline is cloning the other project, the project is also in the access list of the other project.
On further research for the related issue, I found the following threads:

https://forum.gitlab.com/t/gitlab-runner-no-access-to-private-repository-http-basic-access-denied/82118/4
Gitlab Pipeline failing "remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied"

The above thread asked to add the clone_url attribute in the config.toml of the runner.
[[runners]]
  url = "http://gitlab.example.com"
  clone_url = "http://gitlab.example.com"

gitlab version: GitLab Community Edition v16.8.1

How exactly do you get this error? Please [edit] your question to add a [mre]
